# Allow registered users of a Wordpress site to create favorites lists

Tags: wordpress, listview, registration, user-registration, favorites

I've been building a Wodrdpress site lately. It's going to have free registration. I want it to have one and only certain feature for registered users. They should be able to create favorites lists. I mean is that they could favorite certain posts with something like a "like button" and view and edit all their favorites on a certain place like a listview. They shouldn't be able to comment, edit, upload or have any other interaction with the posts. I understand that this can by arranged by giving different permissions to the users. Although I have two questions.
1) Can you suggest some practices/plugins to feature a free registration for the users?
2) Can you suggest some practices/plugins so that registered users can create favorites lists as I explained above?
In case you need further info feel free to ask.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For point 2:

Check out this plugin:

https://favoriteposts.com/

Users are able to add posts and even pages to favorites list.